# Split comma delimited cell into columns

Tags: excel, vba, cell, transpose, delimited

Soo ive found a lot of similar questions but nothing that really fits what im looking to do, and im a little bit stuck.

Basically what im looking to do is have a cell (in this instance, A1), that has multiple values separated by commas (always 4 values), and then have it split into separate rows along columns.

Example

```
A1[10,9,8,6]
```

Needs to Become

```
a10[10], b10[9], c10[8], d10[6]
```

The current code im working with is :

```
Dim X As Variant
X = Split(Range("A1").Value, ",")              

Range("a10").Resize(UBound(X) - LBound(X) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(X)
```

This outputs the data vertically down a column though, when i need it to be outputted as i have shown above

Comment: `Range("a10").Resize(1, UBound(X) - LBound(X) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(X)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're resizing `Range("A10")` in to a *column* range.

The `Resize` method takes two arguments, both optional:

```
.Resize(_rows_, _columns_)
```

You have only supplied the first argument, which resizes A10 to a specified number of *rows*. For example, `Debug.Print Range("A10").Resize(10).Address` should give you: `$A$10:$A$19`, when what you want is `$A$10:$J$10`.

Do this instead:

```
Range("a10").Resize(1, UBound(X) - LBound(X) + 1).Value = X
```

Also you're removing the call to `Application.Transpose`, since the array is already in a row, you don't need to transpose it (previously you had to transpose it from a row, *to* a column).

ALSO the result of the Split function is always a 0-based array, even if you have `Option Base 1`.  **So you can simply do:**

```
Range("a10").Resize(1, UBound(X) + 1).Value = X
```

Alternatively, omit the first argument but include a comma to indicate that you're only passing the *second* argument:

```
Range("a10").Resize(, UBound(X) + 1).Value = X
```

The other method as Pieter suggests below would be to record (and modify) a macro using the built-in Text-to-Columns functionality.  I don't think this will work for your case, because you're taking values from one row and putting them in another row. The built-in text-to-columns only outputs to the *same* row, so a custom split like you have created is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks heaps David! im still having a bit of trouble though.

With the changes it does output across columns, however it will only do the first value (in this case '10') across all 4 columns (a10[10], b10[10], c10[10], d10[10]), how can i fix this? thanks heaps for the reply! cheers J

Comment: Hmmm get rid of `Application.Transpose`

Comment: that did it! would there be any way to make there a gap in between the cells the values are entered into as well? 
ie a10,c10,e10,g10 instead of a10,b10,c10,d10?

Thanks mate really appreciate the help

Comment: There's a way to do it; it's not overly complicated but it would have to involve iteration in a `For Each ... Loop`, can't be done in a single statement like above. If this answered the original question, please consider "accepting" it, and if you have trouble with the `For Each ...` loop, it would be best to ask as a separate question :)

Answer (score 0):

Select the column containing the CSV values (Column A it seems in your example) and then from the **Data Ribbon** Data Tools group launch the **Text to Columns wizard. Specify your column s bein delimited with comma as the delimiter and watch the wizard do it's thing.

In order to program this operation in VBA, run it manually while recording a macro and then inspect and edit the macro.